# replacing {MAX(IF())} array formula with vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

trying to replicate the following in VBA to improve runtime (have 10s of thousands of rows)

I basically want to get the max value for each unique symbol
Already have the unique symbols, symbols and values as named ranges

Current array formula is

```
{=MAX(IF(symbols=D2, values, 0))}
```

for each cell

Comment: I'm not going to say it won't perform better but formulas and the Excel engine are typically waaaay more performant than VBA.

Comment: @Skin it depends.

Comment: @ch2831 why don't you share your Workbook with the data? What is the current runtime and what is your goal? How bad do you need it? Is this something you will need to use regularly on different data sets? If this task is a one-time thing, you better off letting it calculate the slow way and then replace the formulas with result values.

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA MaxIf (Formula)

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VBAMaxIf()
    
    Const sAddress As String = "symbols"
    Const vAddress As String = "values"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const uCol As String = "D"
    Const dCol As String = "E" ' adjust the destination (resulting) column!
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, uCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow < fRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim urg As Range
    Set urg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, uCol), ws.Cells(lRow, uCol))

    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = urg.EntireRow.Columns(dCol)
    Dim dFormula As String: dFormula = "=MAX(IF(" _
        & ws.Range(sAddress).Address & "=" _
        & ws.Cells(fRow, uCol).Address(0, 0) & "," _
        & ws.Range(vAddress).Address & ",0))"
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    drg.Formula = dFormula
    drg.FormulaArray = drg.FormulaR1C1
    drg.Value = drg.Value
 
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```